# Mysql beween 2 timefields include nextday

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, between

I want to select rows which are between 2 time-fields.
This is working fine

```
$hour = date('H:i');
$time = " AND ( ( time1 IS NULL AND time2 IS NULL ) OR ( '$hour'  BETWEEN  time1 AND time2 ) ) ";
```

But my problem is, that the call must work on queries where time1 can be larger than time2 too.

```
like time1=18:00:00 and time2=02:00:00
```

In this case, the query must match eg. 01:00:00 too?

Is there a way to do this in sql directly ( instead of PHP )?

Comment: Why not adding one day to time 2?

Comment: since you need to consider day breaks, you need to compare DATES, not just times.

Comment: Cannot add day to time, becomes the rows are containing weekly rules for updating discount_prices. Another field contains the "days of week"

Comment: You don't add the day to the content of the table, you just add it temporary within you query. Try `$hour BETWEEN DATE_ADD(time1, INTERVAL 1 DAY), time2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think it is a good idea to get the time in the application code and then compare to values in the database.  MySQL offers many functions to manipulate datetimes.

I think the logic that you want is:

```
AND ((time1 < time2 and '$hour' BETWEEN time1 AND time2) or
     (time1 > time2 and '$hour' NOT BETWEEN time1 and time2)
    )
```

Comment: thank you. I just chaned ... "BETWEEN time2 and time1" on second row and it works perfect.